# Error on using googmaps api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Im getting the following error on trying to  use an web service from google api maps:

{
   "error_message" : "Requests to this API must be over SSL.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

the url used to invoke the web service:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=my_key=Rua+Vergueiro,+1883,+S%C3%A3o+Paulo,+Brazil&sensor=true

method used to call the web service:

```
enter code here

public static String httpPost(String urlStr) throws Exception {
    String novaUrl = urlStr.trim();

    novaUrl = urlStr.replaceAll(" ", "+");
    novaUrl = novaUrl.replaceAll("\r", "");
    novaUrl = novaUrl.replaceAll("\t", "");
    novaUrl = novaUrl.replaceAll("\n", "");

    URL url = new URL(novaUrl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);

    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urldecoded");

    // Create the form content
    OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
    writer.close();
    out.close();

    // Buffer the result into a string
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(line);
    }

    rd.close();
    conn.disconnect();

    Spanned retorno = Html.fromHtml(sb.toString());

    return retorno.toString();
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this URL. Error just because of http and https. https is used for secure line.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=my_key=Rua+Vergueiro,+1883,+S%C3%A3o+Paulo,+Brazil&sensor=true

Now when you click on this you will get some error like this  .. **The provided API key is invalid.**

For that just provide correct API key that you retrieved from Google Console.

Comment: Now, Im getting this error:{
   "error_message" : "This site or IP is not authorized to use this API key.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Comment: As Mentioned please cross check your API key being used .. Please post your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Your given URL :: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=my_key=Rua+Vergueiro,+1883,+S%C3%A3o+Paulo,+Brazil&sensor=true

```
here key=my_key  Here is the problem, please provide correct API key and you problem will be solved.
```

Comment: I removed my key only to post de url.

Comment: after fix the url, Im getting the folloing error:{
   "error_message" : "This site or IP is not authorized to use this API key.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}